# Opening a link in a new tab is working for Firefox but not working for Chrome browser using Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a test where I need to open a link in a new tab. This must work in Firefox and Chrome. I first tried it with the Gmail link on the Google page.

On Firefox it works perfectly, Gmail is opened in a new tab. 
But on Chrome the Gmail page is opened in the same window and the menu remains open after right click. Has anyone come across this problem?

Beneath is my sample code.

Firefox code:

```
FirefoxProfile myprofile;
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();            
myprofile = profile.getProfile("SeleniumAuto");             
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");    
driver.manage().window().maximize();

Actions a = new Actions(driver);
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a"));
a.moveToElement(e);
a.contextClick(e).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
 .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Chrome code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--test-type");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");    
driver.manage().window().maximize();*/    

Actions a = new Actions(driver);
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a"));
a.moveToElement(e);
a.contextClick(e).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
 .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue. Apparently, ARROW_DOWN won't work, so I tried using the keys combination and it works for me. The code is as follows:

1) opening in a new tab with focus still on current tab

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(your_path)));
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(your_path)).click();
actions.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
```

2) opening in a new tab and moving to the new tab

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(your_path)));
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
actions.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(your_path)).click();
actions.keyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
actions.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that easily using Selenium. Use the Key commands (Ctrl +T) to open a new tab and then use Ctrl +Tab (Ctrl +\t) command to switch to newly opened tab and perform whatever is necessary. It would go something like this

```
//open a  new tab
WebElement e= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(abc)).sendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
//switch control to new tab
e.sendKeys(Keys.Control + "\t");
{
    perform some function here
    enter code here
}
//switch back to old tab
e.sendKeys(Keys.Control + "\t");
```

This will work if the browser only has two tabs open, because then it will use the Tab key to move between the two open tabs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome try this:

```
Actions a = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement e = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath(your_path));
a.moveToElement(e).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click().build().perform();
```